# I'm having problems trying to get my userContent.css to work in Firefox 23

Tags: firefox, css

I've got a simple `chrome/userContent.css` in my profile:

```
% cat ~/Library/Application\ Support/Firefox/Profiles/7h7pwntq.default/chrome/userContent.css
@-moz-document domain(reddit.com) { 
  textarea {
    font-family: Monaco, monospace;
  }
}
%
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. I'm sure this is the right profile directory (it's the only one), and I've tried reloading pages and restarting Firefox to no effect.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
@-moz-document domain(reddit.com) { 
  textarea {
    font-family: Monaco, monospace;
  }
}
```

to

```
@-moz-document domain(reddit.com) { 
  textarea {
    font-family: Monaco, monospace !important;
  }
}
```

So you need to add `!important` to over-ride the web page defaults and to use your own settings.

Comment: Worked! Edited, restarted the browser, good to go.

Comment: Can this be applied to properties that are commented out? For example, I want to disable the "position: fixed;" rule of the top bar of this site so it doesn't follow me everywhere I scroll. So I commented it out in the ".top-bar._fixed" selector in my userContent.css file. But this was not able to override the rule in primary.css. Is there a special syntax for forcing this rule to override the default rule?

Comment: @NicholasCousar you are asking one or two different questions here: 1. "How can I disable a CSS rule on a website using userContent.css?" and/or 2. "How do I change a position: fixed CSS rule to the default using userContent.css?" Please ask a new question on this site.